# validating form with an address from maps

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, maps

I have an input form I want to validate with Bootstrap (has-success) or CSS (border-color).

The form has a google-maps listener, maps suggests auto-completions if I put in letters, e.g. "Los" probably suggests Los Angeles. How can I validate the form, when there is a valid address in it? Does an onchange function make sense?

Comment: need to narrow down what your specific issues are as well as define what is valid and what isn't

Comment: if the user chooses an address from the maps auto completion suggestions by clicking on it or scrolling through it with the arrow keys and pushing enter, this address is a valid one. if he only types "abcxyz" into the form and doesn't choose from the maps "helper", it is not valid and the form should glow red.